# How to set object type props value in an enzyme for a react component?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I tried two ways,

1.

```
const wrapper=shallow(<ActiveConversation />)
wrapper.setProps({activeConversation:c,agent:a});
expect(wrapper.prop('messagesList')).to.equal(messagesList);
```

2.

```
const wrapper=shallow(<ActiveConversation messagesList={messagesList}
       agent={agent} contactFormState={d} tagSuggestions={t}/>);
```

But still both props goes on undefined

Comment: have you seen [this link](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setProps.md)?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `props` correctly. The problem is that `wrapper.prop()` returns `undefined` in your particular case. This happens because actually `wrapper` isn't `<ActiveConversation />`, it's what it returns. So your `prop()` call tries to get a `prop` with `messagesList` key from the root node returned from `<ActiveConversation />`.

For example, if `<ActiveConversation />` component renders something like this:

```
<div className='conversation'>
  <ConversationRenderer
    messagesList={this.props.messagesList}
    activeConversation={this.props.activeConversation} 
    info={info? true: false}
  /> 
  {info} 
</div>
```

`wrapper.prop('messagesList')` will try to find prop in this node `<div className='conversation'>` (not it's children), and since there isn't one, will return `undefined`.

In order to pass the test `<ActiveConversation />` should render something like:

```
<div 
   messagesList={this.props.messagesList}
   className='conversation'
>
  <ConversationRenderer
    messagesList={this.props.messagesList}
    activeConversation={this.props.activeConversation} 
    info={info? true: false}
  /> 
  {info} 
</div>
```

But I guess that's not what you want.

By the way, but your test seems to be meaningless. What's the point of it? To test if a `prop` is set? It's al about `react` functionality, leave it for facebook to test :)

Comment: Thanks Lazarev...but i have div as u said    <div className='conversation'>
          <ConversationRenderer messagesList={this.props.messagesList} activeConversation={this.props.activeConversation} info={info? true: false}/>
          {info}
        </div>

Comment: Yes, so `wrapper.prop('messagesList')` will try to get the prop with key `messagesList` in `<div className='conversation'>`. `<div className='conversation'>` has only `className` and no props, that is why `undefined` is returned.

Comment: The problem i think is with the objects i pass to my props.They are not getting assigned properly.

Comment: Just do a `console.log(this.props.messagesList)`  in `<ActiveConversation>`  render method and you'll see. I'm convinced they do.

Comment: those results undefined and null at times

Comment: You've done it this way? `const wrapper=shallow(<ActiveConversation messagesList={messagesList}
       agent={agent} contactFormState={d} tagSuggestions={t}/>);`?

Comment: I am defining the objects improperly i hope

Comment: Hey @Lazarev Alexandr...I am setting the prop values but when I run the test and console its debug I am recieving     ``` <div className="conversation">
<ConversationRenderer messagesList={{...}} activeConversation={{...}} info={false} />
</div>
```

Comment: Is the {{...}} indicates null or invisible??